# SP2013 On Premises: CustomAction Welcome Menu not visible

Tags: 2013, custom-actions

I am trying to add a custom action to the Welcome menu, right below the Sign Out button.
Here are the steps I followed:

1) Created an Empty element called CustomActions and edited the Elements.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="MyCustomAction"
    Description="This is my custom action."
    Title="Open Application Page"
    GroupId="SiteActions"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    Sequence="10">
    <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/SPCustomAction/MyAppPage.aspx"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

2) Created a feature with scope Site, and added this item to the feature.

3) Deployed.

Am I missing something?
I also tried creating a SPUserCustomAction programmatically on the FeatureActivated, but it's not showing up either.

Any advise?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the feature is activated? 

The only other thing I can see that differs from my custom action definitions (SP2013 on-premise) is the GroupId - you could try 'PersonalActions' instead of 'SiteActions', and the Sequence number - try '1000'.

Comment: +1 For the promp reply and correct response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GroupId="PersonalActions"` and `Sequence="1000"`